# How can I add padding to a jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, padding, jtextfield

How can I add some padding to a jtextfield?
I've tried `tf.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));` which doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the UI is setting its own border on the text field, overriding the margin you set. You can see a warning to this effect in the javadoc of `setMargin()`.

The solution is to let the UI set a border, then squeeze in another border of your own:

```
field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        field.getBorder(), 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
```

Answer (score 5):

you have look at [CompoundBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), there you can set `LineBorder(Color.gray, 1)` and with

```
EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is using `BorderFactory`

```
field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is years too late, but actually, if you want a consistent look and feel in Java, you should be editing the UI so *every* text field you create doesn't need its own special code.  So, taking from Russel Zahniser's example above:

```
Border tfBorder = UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");
Border newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(tfBorder, 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));

UIManager.setBorder("TextField.border", newBorder);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourTextFeildVariable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(yourTextFeildVariable.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
```

This is working 100%

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can apply this to a textbox already created with a border

```
jTextField1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(jTextField1.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6)));
```