# How to put padding around JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I was wondering how does one put spacing and set the size of a JTextArea component in Java.

eg

```
//I've tried
        questInfo = new JTextArea(20,30);
        questInfo.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
```

When I preview the gui, It just shows JTextArea filling in the pane from top to bottom and left to right, no spacing in between the pane

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, this happens due to UI overriding the margin. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792651/how-can-i-add-padding-to-a-jtextfield). You might resolve it using:

```
questInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        field.getBorder(), 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
```